How to remove default blog page?
I am a new in WordPress development I took an online course and there is a question related to the blog page. I did a blog page with my default content, but once I switch a theme from twenty-twenty-one to Twenty-twenty four (full-screen editing) and open the web-site and click on the Blog link it navigates me to the default blog page - the same one as presented on the "preview" for the theme. However, if I open the admin console and click Pages->All pages and choose Blog it my page appears as expected, but on the actual web site it is a default one.
What am I missing?

It's going to be very hard to answer this question without the URL - if you can share the URL you are working with it would be more helpful.
To me it sounds like you had previously created a static page for your blog and set it under Settings > Reading so that you could have a custom layout for your blog. Now when switching to the 20-24 theme your header menu is linking to an "automatic" blog archive instead of your custom created page.
You may just need to edit the theme under Appearance > Editor > Patterns > Header and click on the menu to modify the blog link so it's pointing to your custom blog page.
